How does DNS work in wg-quick?
I am trying to setup a VPN with two hops: traffic coming from the client gets routed through a VPS server and then to Mullvad VPN:

Everything works just fine, but I'm not sure if the DNS is working as intended. I'd like my DNS requests to take the same route as every other packet: from the client to the VPS server and then to Mullvad VPN.
My VPS server runs an unbound DNS server that routes the whole traffic to the Mullvad DNS, and the Mullvad WireGuard configuration has dns = 127.0.0.1. You can find the config file below.
I have some troubles understanding how the "DNS" parameter works in the wg-quick client configuration, specifically:

If I put dns = "10.8.0.1" (WireGuard IP address of the VPS server), the DNS doesn't work
If I put dns = 1.1.1.1, or any IP really, the request gets routed through the VPS server and then to Mullvad, never reaching 1.1.1.1 or any IP I put there. To be clear: the DNS request gets resolved, it just always goes through VPS server and then Mullvad, basically ignoring whatever I put in the DNS argument.
If I remove dns = ... altogether, then I'm not sure what happens, I see from dnsleak that my requests come from Bulgaria, and my VPS is hosted there, so maybe it's using the VPS DNS?

Here's my configurations:
client WireGuard configuration
[Interface]
Address = 10.8.0.2/24
DNS = 1.1.1.1
PrivateKey = redacted

[Peer]
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = IP:51820
PublicKey = redacted

VPS server "client<>server" WireGuard configuration:
[interface]
PrivateKey = redacted
Address = 10.8.0.1/24
PostUp = iptables -I FORWARD -i %i -j REJECT
PostUp = iptables -I FORWARD -o %i -j REJECT
PostUp = iptables -I FORWARD -i %i -o mull -j ACCEPT
PostUp = iptables -I FORWARD -o %i -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

PreDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -o mull -j ACCEPT
PreDown = iptables -D FORWARD -o %i -j REJECT
PreDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j REJECT
ListenPort = 51820

[peer]
PublicKey = redacted
AllowedIPs = 10.8.0.2/32

VPS server "server<>mullvad" WireGuard configuration:
[Interface]
PrivateKey = redacted
Address = IP/32
DNS = 127.0.0.1

#### Routing configuration ####
Table = 123
PostUp = ip rule add from 10.8.0.0/24 table 123
PostUp = ip rule add from IP/32 table 123
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o %i -j MASQUERADE

PreDown = ip rule del from 10.8.0.0/24 table 123
PreDown = ip rule del from IP/32 table 123
PreDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o %i -j MASQUERADE
#### End Routing configuration ####

[Peer]
PublicKey = redacted
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0,::0/0
Endpoint = IP:51820

VPS server DNS unbound configuration:
server:
    verbosity: 1
    interface: 127.0.0.1
    interface: 10.8.0.1
    interface: 0.0.0.0

forward-zone:
    name: "."
    forward-addr: 100.64.0.3 # mullvad dns ip


There's nothing special about DNS. Wireguard is not aware of DNS. DNS is generally not aware of what interface it's transported over.

@vidarlo Yeah I get that :) I realized that my question might not be totally clear, I tried to improve it, but the fact is that I don't understand how the "DNS = ..." argument in a wg-quick configuration affects the DNS requests that are made. Take my second point: by putting DNS = 1.1.1.1 and following the DNS requests with dnstop, I can see that the client is making a request to the vps, basically "ignoring" that I put 1.1.1.1 there.

wg-quick itself (which is really a shell script) would call resolvconf for the DNS= line, while resolvconf could really be the "real" one or a symlink to resolvectl (which talks to systemd-resolved).
IIRC the "real" resolvconf would mess with your /etc/resolv.conf. I don't really have much experience with it so I don't know the details about how it manage stuff exactly.
If it's systemd-resolved and resolvectl that you are using, things could be quite complicated I think, because systemd-resolved itself has different "modes" of operation, depending on e.g. whether /etc/resolv.conf is a regular file or a symlink (and if it's a symlink, which file it points to).
I think if you are using the "recommended mode" (i.e., /etc/resolv.conf points to a systemd-generated file that have the resolved stub at 127.0.0.53 as the only DNS server), it would probably set the link DNS server of the wireguard interface to what you set in DNS=.
AFAIK the "recommended mode" is prone to DNS leak, since at least by default, when resolved receive DNS requests, it would forward them to all link DNS servers.
Personally I don't use DNS= (on system that has resolved working in the "recommended mode"). Instead I have something like:
PreUp=resolvectl dns wlan0 ""
PostUp=resolvectl dns %i 192.168.144.49
PostDown=resolvectl revert wlan0

(I'm not interested in setting up a general "kill switch".)
IIRC there was a time that the "fake" resolvconf can't really be used by wg-quick, because some switches wg-quick use aren't supported. I have no idea if it's still the case now.


If I put dns = "10.8.0.1" (wireguard IP address of the VPS server), the DNS doesn't work

This is probably either because the firewall on the VPS server drops/rejects (non-loopback) inbound DNS requests, at least those ingress via the wireguard interface.

If I put dns = 1.1.1.1, or any IP really, the request gets routed through the VPS server and then to mullvad

This is probably because the Mullvad client adds a DNAT rule that redirects all traffics with destination port 53 to the set DNS server (namely 127.0.0.1) in the PREROUTING chain (assuming you are not using like the "vanilla" wg-quick for Mullvad; or if you are, maybe there's a PostUp= in the conf).

If I remove dns = ... altogether, then I'm not sure what happens

Your client would stick to the "original" DNS server(s).
If it is a host that is covered by only the default route, like 1.1.1.1 (that would normally be), then there should be no difference between having and not having a DNS= line that has the original server as the value.
If it's host that is covered by a non-default route, such as the client's home router, then the DNS resolution would be done without involving your VPS server (or anything beyond), since  with wg-quick's policy / "tricks" for AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, traffics covered by non-default routes are not routed into the tunnel.
